# Regex for alphanumeric and special characters

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I need to define a regular expression that accepts Alphanumeric and the following special characters:
@#$%&*()-_+][';:?.,!

I've come up with:

```
string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%&*+\-_(),+':;?.,![]\s\\/]+$";
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Can someone please let me know what is missing?

Comment: Your code only matches ASCII characters (which may be what you require for your scenario). If you also want to permit Unicode letters, such as `é`, you should use `\w` instead of `a-zA-Z0-9_`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `[]` in the middle need to be escaped*:

```
\[\]
```

You also probably want to anchor the start of the string with a `^`.

---

<sub>* Probably just the `]` but I like to do both for balance.</sub>

Comment: +1 Good answer. Regarding the anchor, however, that depends on his needs. It should be noted to the OP that `^` matches beginning and `$` matches end, and then he can use what he needs.

Comment: how to add char limit to 6-19 chars ?

Comment: @Sreekumar: Instead of the `+` at the end, which means "at least one", just limit it: `{6,19}`

Answer (score 6):

When defining a character class, you will need to escape the closing bracket `]` within, just like "`^`", "`-`" and the escaping sequence `\` itself, which you have done correctly:

```
string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%&*+\-_(),+':;?.,![\]\s\\/]+$";
                                    ^              ^   ^
```

Answer (score 4):

Some of those characters need to be escaped (*, +, etc). The easiest way is to simply escape them all:

```
string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9\@\#\$\%\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\]\[\'\;\:\?\.\,\!]+$";
```

Comment: `*` and `+` are unambiguous inside character sets. Although I usually escape them anyway as good practice, it's not necessary.

Comment: I'd say escaping everything makes nothing but illegibility.

Comment: @minitech, true, thanks for the clarification. Bergi, you have a point, but I'd rather *always* escape any characters which could be interpreted as a special character, even if inside a []-block they wouldn't, so people not too familiar with Regexes don't have to think about whether it means something special or not. Depending on the team you work on, you can be more strict on what should be escaped.

Comment: @carlosfigueira - Thanks for your syntax. But can you please tell what should be done if I want to have atleast 'one smaller case', atleast one biiger case and atleast one number and atleast one special character?

Comment: @Bergi I would say that it makes it highly legible, especially if you were to forgo the `a-zA-Z0-9` and `\_` for a simple `\w`.

Comment: @tuespetre: You mean `[\w\@\#\$\%\&\*\(\)\-\+\]\[\'\;\:\?\.\,\!]`? That would make me wonder whether the author meant to escape a `w` character or if he really meant the character class. Classes and single characters should be easily distinguishable.

Comment: @Bergi A regex like should have some surrounding context, like `var passwordRegex = ...` that makes the intentions behind the regex clear enough. It's a strokes/folks kind of thing anyways, I function better with visually 'neat' things.