# Use Regex to find parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, parentheses

I need to find if a string any kind of parentheses ( ) { } [ ]. These parentheses can be in any order and can appear nay where in the string.
How to do that in C# using RegEx?

Comment: Have you tried a regular expression yet? It should consist of just one [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) containing all these parenthesis.

Comment: You'll just have to escape the square brackets within the character class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this for the regex pattern:

```
string pattern = @"[\(\)\[\]\{\}]+$";
```

Also here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644318/regex-for-alphanumeric-and-special-characters) to another question to check for alpha numeric and special characters.